# How to scale Bulk Scheduled tasks on a Timeline in GCP?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, architecture, scaling, google-cloud-tasks

We have microservice to deliver notification on a timeline with multiple channels(Push Notification, Email, SMS).

So we persist every scheduled notification in a DB and run a CRON for every 3 hours to query notifications scheduled to deliver within the next 3 hours. in which we push the result into PUSH Queue(Cloud Tasks) to run on time.

This solution works well and good, but when no. of the tasks increase eg: 5k task at the same time, PUSH QUEUE dispatching with delay.

Though I try to tweak the PUSH QUEUE dispatch rate and concurrency. The HTTP handlers are not scaling to process such level traffic instantly(GAE scales gradually). So it delivers the notifications with delay.

The reason we do this way to support.

- Cancellation/Content update on the scheduled task at any time before it delivers.

So What's the optimal way to run all the scheduled tasks(like 5k to 20k) on the timeline without delay?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/manage-cloud-task-scaling#queue) on Cloud Tasks that touches on exactly the issue that you facing, I recommend you take a look at it and check if any of the solutions proposed would be applicable in you scenario, let me know if it's not and we can discuss it further.

Comment: Sure thanks, will check.

Comment: @RafaelLemos the solution what they mentioned https://share.anysnap.app/fcVUBLKIdNI3

I'm already doing that with queue rate 500/s to increase traffic gradually. But that introducing more delay.

Comment: What type of scaling are you using in App Engine? Increasing the number of instances and distributing these tasks among them would also help with that.

Comment: automatic-scaling,  with default min and max pending latency.

Comment: And how many instances are created during the processing of the tasks? As a test, try changing to manual scaling and slightly increase the number of instances from the number I just asked above and check if there are any changes.

Comment: thanks for replying, Yes It will definitely work and reduce the delay.  But in case of the cost, will increase radically. 

I'm experimenting like with more number of queues based on the traffic and reducing the GAE HTTP handler latency to let Task Queues to lease more tasks as fast it can.

Comment: ok, let me know what comes out of this test that you making when it's done if you need any advice.